# JavaScript Array- adding the values together

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, addition

I'm trying to take numbers inputted by a user. Store those number inside an array and then add up all values inside the array to get a total number. I'm using numbers 1 -7 to test.
I print the output of the array and I get:

```
 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

returned so it seems that storing the data in an array is working. However when I try to add the values inside the array I get:

```
01234567
```

Which makes it look like the function is just pushing the numbers together. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var again = "no";
var SIZE = 7;
var pints = [];
var totalPints = 0;
var averagePints = 0;
var highPints = 0;
var lowPints = 0;

getPints(pints[SIZE]);

getTotal(pints[SIZE]);

println(pints);
println(totalPints);


function getPints()
{
    counter = 0;
    while (counter < 7)
    {
    pints[counter] = prompt("Enter the number of pints");
    counter = counter + 1;
    }

}

function getTotal()
{
    counter = 0;
    totalPints = 0
    for (var counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++)
    {
        totalPints += pints[counter]    
    }

}
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't know that you're trying to add numbers, and it's treating your numbers as strings.  Try putting a `+` in front of the variable name or user `parseInt` or to ensure it's converted to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parseInt` to convert the `pints` values like this

```
totalPints += parseInt(pints[counter], 10);
```

And you don't have to hardcode the length like this

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++)
```

instead you can use `pints.length` like this

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < pints.length; counter++)
```

Comment: Outstanding thank you. I figured it was something that simple but when searching for help all the examples had arrays with strings so it wasn't to helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your array contains the strings instead of their integer values, instead of

```
totalPints += pints[counter];
```

Try using something like this -

```
totalPints += parseInt(pints[counter], 10);
```

Comment: When using `parseInt()`, you should always add the radix as a second argument to ensure the value is interpreted as a base-10 number: `parseInt(pints[counter], 10)`

Answer (score 0):

That happens since each number is read as a string, not a number. Change:

```
pints[counter] = prompt("Enter the number of pints");
```

to:

```
pints[counter] = +prompt("Enter the number of pints");
```

to convert the value to a Number so that you get addition instead of concatenation from the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
01234567
```

This is the output produced by your code. Note that values in the array are in quotes, so that means their type is `String.` When using `+` with strings you get string concatenation.

That's why you have to convert them to a number.

There are multiple ways to do so.

```
-> parseInt("5")
-> 5
-> "5" * 1
-> 5
-> Number("5")
-> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
totalPints += pints[counter]
```

to

```
totalPints += parseInt(pints[counter])
```

`parseInt` will convert the string values to integers.